WhatsApp call notifications on apple watch
This requires a small trick I have not figured out yet. I have my WhatsApp notifications displayed on my iPhone but not delivered to my Apple Watch, simply because I don’t want my wrist buzzing with every message. However, I’d like to receive notifications for WhatsApp calls.
Is there any way to do this?
